# Field annotated with @Value is returning null

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using ConstraintValidator implementation to validate if character is above certain height defined in application.properties and I have encountered a problem where the field minimumHeight with @Value is always null. I have also tried constructor injection but then it gives out error as follows:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.miquido.Validator.CharacterValidator.<init>()
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3585) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2271) ~[na:na]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.privilegedactions.NewInstance.run(NewInstance.java:41) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.3.Final.jar:6.2.3.Final]
```

This is my validator:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;


public class CharacterValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidCharacter, Long> {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigProperties configProperties;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidCharacter constraintAnnotation) {
        ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Long value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        configProperties = SpringApplicationContextService.getApplicationContext().getBean(ConfigProperties.class);
        if (value == null) {
            return true;
        }
        formatMessage(context);
        return value >= configProperties.getMinimum();
    }

    private void formatMessage(ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        String msg = context.getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate();
        String formattedMsg = String.format(msg, configProperties.getMinimum());
        context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(formattedMsg)
                .addConstraintViolation();
    }
}
```

```java
    @Target({ElementType.FIELD})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Constraint(validatedBy = CharacterValidator.class)
    public @interface ValidCharacter {
    
        String message() default "Character must be higher than %s";
    
        Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    
        Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    }
```

**EDIT 1**
I have edited my code as @antey13 suggested, but still the minimumHeight is null.

**EDIT 2**
I have added SpringApplicationContextService with static getter that returns ApplicationContext and I inject the bean manually in implementantion of ConstraintValidator.

```
@Service
public class SpringApplicationContextService implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        SpringApplicationContextService.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: A `ConstraintValidator` isn't managed by Spring thus is not going to get any of the advantages of Spring like auto wiring or value processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check the following bullet points?

- The file is loaded in the correct way
- CharacterValidator is a bean of Spring
- The class has a correct construct
- initialize method exists (the error in this question seems to be for this method)

```java
    @Override
    public void initialize(ContactNumberConstraint contactNumber) {
    }
```

You can follow the next links:

1. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-constraint-validator
2. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

Answer (score 0):

Remove the constructor and add generic params ConstraintValidator<ValidCharacter, String>. Make sure that you are using spring validation (spring-boot-starter-validation for spring boot), because in another case @Value won't work because spring will not be aware of your validator class

Comment: I have applied your suggestion, but still it gives me null value

Comment: In this case, can you share your application.properties or yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@Component` on `CharacterValidator` class

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).